# Eliminating Left Recursion from this weird Expression Grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar, left-recursion

I am trying to write an Expression Grammar where there are 3 operators '+','-' and '/'. The multiplication operator is implied by juxtaposition as in:

```
(1+2)(3+4 5)
```

Here is the Grammar:

```
S -> A ('+' A)*

A -> B ('-' B)*

B -> C ('/' C)*

C -> D ( D )*

D ->ID
    |Num
    |'(' S ')'
```

I am using Xtext which uses the ANTLR parser and it says this is left recursive on Rule C. If I were to change Rule 4 as

```
C -> D ('\*' D)*
```

Then error is eliminated. I am confused. Would like some help!

Comment: What is the non-terminal E?

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo. Edited.

Comment: I don't think it's the problem, but your rules are redundant.  E.g. `S->A('+' A)*` already allows for derivation of a single `A`, so `S->A` is unnecessary.  Same for all the others.

Comment: Okay. I removed those. I am pretty new with parsing. Please bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Xtext, but Antlr 4 has no problem with this grammar:

```
grammar Expr; 
s: a ('+' a)* ;
a: b ('-' b)* ;
b: c ('/' c)* ;
c: d ( d )* ;
d: ID | NUM |'(' s ')' ;
ID: [a-z][a-z0-9]* ;
NUM: [0-9]+ ;
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

When I compile and run your example `(1+2)(3+4 5)`, I get this parse tree:
[image: parse tree]

It may be Xtext is using an old version of Antlr. It's a great bit of software, but in older versions especially it's not perfect. This grammar is not left-recursive by the standard definition. It's possible Antlr is transforming it into a simpler grammar that *is* left recursive, but that would be a bug that's apparently been fixed.

So if my guess is correct, you'll be successful with the following explicitly "simplified" grammar:

```
grammar Expr; 
s: a ap ;
ap: '+' a ap | /* eps */ ;
a: b bp ;
bp: '-' b bp | /* eps */ ;
b: c cp ;
cp: '/' c cp | /* eps */ ;
c: d dp ;
dp: d dp | ;
d: ID | NUM |'(' s ')' ;
ID: [a-z][a-z0-9]* ;
NUM: [0-9]+ ;
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

New parse tree:[image: new parse tree]

Comment: This is exactly the parse tree I would like to generate. However, I am stuck with Xtext which uses ANTLR 3.2, it seems. I would just like to know how to left factor this grammar.

Comment: I think I will have to convince my group to switch to ANTLR 4. There are going to be a lot of such Left Recursions ahead. Thank You!

Comment: You can't factor out left recursion because the grammar is not left-recursive. There must be a bug in ANTLR 3 that's causing it to rewrite into something that is left-recursive. Best guess is in rewriting the Kleene star operations as  grammar rules.

Comment: @KartikSayani Thanks. I added a potential workaround. I'm interested in whether it works in your environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The Xtext still prompts a Left Recursion on Rule C and DP. I think the problem is with the parenthesis. Both C and DP call for D which calls for '(' S ')' and it recurses?

Comment: By definition left recursion involves non-terminals in the leftmost position of rule right-hand-sides.  The paren prevents that.  This grammar would make a fine LL(1) parser.  This is definitely a bug in ANTLR 3.

Comment: Either a bug in ANTLR 3 or something that Xtext doesn't allow. I'll check it out. Thank a lot!

Comment: can you please tell me how you generated those parse trees?

Comment: @KartikSayani See the example on the ANTLR web page.  It's built in to ANTLR 4.